# Search suggestion works, but search itself does not

Tags: magento2, search

When I use the quicksearch in my webshop, it shows the products that match (part of) what I type and even includes how many products match.

However, when I hit enter (basically loading `catalogsearch/result/?q=SEARCHTHIS`, I always get

> Your search returned no results.

How can I fix that?

Comment: Have you tried reindexing catalogsearch_fulltext?